# routing to MongoDB ObjectId via ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, servicestack

I am developing a ServiceStack api and I am having trouble routing to:

```
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

I've tried setting up a custom binding model as follows:

```
  public class ObjectIdModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            return result == null ? ObjectId.Empty : ObjectId.Parse((string)result.ConvertTo(typeof(string)));
        }
    }


protected void Application_Start()
    {

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ObjectId), new ObjectIdModelBinder());
```

This is in the AppHost.cs

Routes
                .Add("/user")
                .Add("/user/{Id}");

When I tried to access the api through the url:

```
http://localhost:1000/api/user/1234567
```

I get the following error:

error Code
        RequestBindingException
    message
        Unable to bind request
    stack Trace
        at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)

Binding to a basic native type works, any idea how to fix something like this?

Answer (score 1):

passing a valid id such as '51cbda57d845130cc86322fd' instead of 1234567 correctly mapped it to the [Bson] Id property.